# create an empty list of list in scheme(racket)

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am a beginner in Scheme so I apologize if it's a really basic question for you.

I am trying to create an empty list of lists which will be filled afterwards. The correct way to implement this is using objects but I need to do it using a list.

Suppose we have a university department and students. Each student has some specific fields such as name, gpa etc. These fields are determined by the user so the number of fields is unknown. At the end, we have something like we have in database structures:

create a table(table-name is given by the user as a parameter) with the columns(again, given by the user).

visually speaking, list of lists should look like this:

```
table-name---name1---name2---name3---...
-----------------field11----field21---field31--....
-----------------field12----field22---field32--....
.......
```

after creating the list, I should have the ability to insert records into it.

Comment: What purpose does the inner empty list serve?

Comment: Each element of a list is a list. So the big list corresponds to the whole department whereas each list in the big list corresponds to a student, I mean a record in database. But the number of fields, I mean the length of each list is unknown, determined by the user.

Comment: When you have some student information, you can create a list for that student and add it to the outer list. Until then, there is no need to have any empty inner lists.

Comment: At first, I need to create it as empty. Think it like creating a table in a database with some columns. Even if I don't have any information, with this definition I should be able to create a list, which is going to be filled after some information will be received.

Comment: I think of the outer list as the table. Each of the inner lists is a row of the table. You don't add rows to a table until you have some data for the row.

Comment: What @RSahu is saying is that there is no deference between a list with keys that point to nil and a list without those keys in the first place.

Comment: You are right but the problem is the number of fields. When creating a table, user will determine the number of fields(or columns in database) and I don't know how to create a list with the fields. The user will write something like:
(create-table 'students '(name id gpa))
Once again, this is my first time in Scheme so I am very unaware of what is going on.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried so far, what happened, and what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a variable :

```
(define student-list '())
```

So student-list is the empty list. You can add whatever you want to it. Imagine you want add a student. You can just add it to the empty list :

```
(set! student-list (cons '(name phone-number etc) student-list))
```

You're just assigning to student-list a new value, which is the previous value of list (the empty list) and the new list you want. And, with the same code, you can add another student.

In Scheme, you don't have to determine the number of fields directly : list are dynamic structures. With `(list stg stg2)`, you can create a list which is `'(stg stg2)`. But you have another operator : cons. This function let you add something to a list : `(cons 'stg3 (list stg stg2))`, and you got the list `'(stg3 stg stg2)`. You added a field and you don't had to "declare" a field or something like that. It's not a fixed array like in C. And if you have a list of list, each list can have a not defined number of fields. So, for example.

```
(define student-list)
;;; This is your first empty list.

(define (add-student ids)
  (set! student-list (cons ids student-list)))
;;; ids is the list of name, etc. of student 
;;; you want to insert in the student-list.
```

This code define a global variable and change it with the data you give to the function add-student. And this can be anything. `'(name phone gpa)` or `'(name gpa)`, etc. However, if you want to pass a list to a function `((define (add-student students ids))` for instance, with students the list of all students), you can't use set!. You'll have to use set-car! and set-cdr!.

As said in comments, you don't have to set a list of nil elements, and complete them after. You can just have an empty variable, and fill it with your data when they come.

Edit : With the above code, I'm doing some side effect. But you have another way : in Scheme, everything has a return value. When you're doing `(+ 1 2)`, you'll have the return value of 3. So if you do `(list (+ 1 2) (+ 1 4))`, you'll have a list `'(3 5)`. So a function has a return value too. In above code, return value is #void, cause set! doesn't have return value. However, you can directly return the list you want. To do it, you can just remove the set!.

```
(define (add-student-second students ids)
  (cons ids students))
```

So if you're doing `(add-student-second '((name1)) (name2))`, you'll got `((name2) (name1))` as a return value. You just have to treat your data as you want after that.

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to do it without using ! ? I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: Edited my post. Hope this answer to your question.